# What does this Python/SQL code do?

Tags: python, sql

So if anyone is knowledgeable on Animal Shelter Manager, I'm looking for some help. I'm trying to figure out what each line of code means.. the first is

from animalcontrol.py

```
def get_animalcontrol_query(dbo):
  return "SELECT ac.*, ac.ID AS ACID, s.SpeciesName, x.Sex AS SexName, " \
    "co.OwnerName AS CallerName, co.HomeTelephone, co.WorkTelephone, co.MobileTelephone, " \
    "o1.OwnerName AS OwnerName, o1.OwnerName AS OwnerName1, o2.OwnerName AS OwnerName2, o3.OwnerName AS OwnerName3, " \
    "o1.OwnerName AS SuspectName, o1.OwnerAddress AS SuspectAddress, o1.OwnerTown AS SuspectTown, o1.OwnerCounty AS SuspectCounty, o1.OwnerPostcode AS SuspectPostcode, " \
    "o1.HomeTelephone AS SuspectHomeTelephone, o1.WorkTelephone AS SuspectWorkTelephone, o1.MobileTelephone AS SuspectMobileTelephone, " \
    "vo.OwnerName AS VictimName, vo.OwnerAddress AS VictimAddress, vo.OwnerTown AS VictimTown, vo.OwnerCounty AS VictimCounty, vo.OwnerPostcode AS VictimPostcode," \
    "vo.HomeTelephone AS VictimHomeTelephone, vo.WorkTelephone AS VictimWorkTelephone, vo.MobileTelephone AS VictimMobileTelephone, " \
    "ti.IncidentName, ci.CompletedName, pl.LocationName " \
    "FROM animalcontrol ac " \
    "LEFT OUTER JOIN species s ON s.ID = ac.SpeciesID " \
    "LEFT OUTER JOIN lksex x ON x.ID = ac.Sex " \
    "LEFT OUTER JOIN owner co ON co.ID = ac.CallerID " \
    "LEFT OUTER JOIN owner o1 ON o1.ID = ac.OwnerID " \
    "LEFT OUTER JOIN owner o2 ON o2.ID = ac.Owner2ID " \
    "LEFT OUTER JOIN owner o3 ON o3.ID = ac.Owner3ID " \
    "LEFT OUTER JOIN owner vo ON vo.ID = ac.VictimID " \
    "LEFT OUTER JOIN pickuplocation pl ON pl.ID = ac.PickupLocationID " \
    "LEFT OUTER JOIN incidenttype ti ON ti.ID = ac.IncidentTypeID " \
    "LEFT OUTER JOIN incidentcompleted ci ON ci.ID = ac.IncidentCompletedID"
```

What does `return "SELECT ac.*, ac.ID AS ACID,` mean.

and if I wanted to differ this code from what it is currently what would I have to change. ei "ac." or "ACID"

I know I will have to change `def get_animalcontrol_query(dbo):`

Comment: `ac.ID as ACID` just means that in the output, the column name will be `ACID` instead of `ac.ID`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: so when it says `SELECT ac.*,`
What are they referring to.

Comment: @RyanKing That means select all the rows from the ac table.  You may want to get a book on basic SQL, or spend some time leaning the basics.  Here is a link I just found that might help you some: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/back-to-basics-sql

Answer (score 0):

The code you've referenced is selecting all the rows from the animalcontrol table and JOINING all the data that is also contained in the species, lksex, owner, pickuplocation, incidenttype, and incidentcompleted tables.  Basically it is taking all the information from the animalcontrol table and looking for related information in each of the other tables, then returning all those results to the user.  For more on 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' see: http://www.1keydata.com/sql/left-outer-join.html The query is also "aliasing" the column names http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp so that the results make sense to the user.

If you want to change this code, you should learn some basic SQL so you understand what you are changing.